# Convert entire column from integer to datetime using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with an entire column that contains integers. I know that these integers were previously datetime values. I want to update all values in this column to be datetimes. There are 1000+ plus rows. I've altered this column from an INT to varchar since all the errors I received didn't like me going from an INT to DATETIME but I am having the same issue with the varchar data type.

Example values in the column: 43873, 40706, 43873, ect

I have tried the following queries:

```
UPDATE WORKER SET INT_TIME = DATEFROMPARTS(INT_TIME,1,1);

UPDATE WORKER SET INT_TIME = CONVERT(datetime,INT_TIME,107);
```

I receive errors like

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string.

INT_TIME is the column I am trying to update all values to a datetime:

[image: INT_TIME is the column I am trying to update all values to a datetime]

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes to date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant. E.g. DATEFROMPARTS and CONVERT are product specific.)

Comment: I am using Microsoft SQL Server Studio

Answer (score 0):

These look like Excel format.  That suggests something like:

```
select dateadd(day, col, '1899-12-30')
```

Comment: What is happening here? This wont update the column, will it?

Comment: @WilliamStahl . . . No.  But then again, you have an INTEGER column so you are going to fail if you try to set the value to a DATE.  This shows you the appropriate conversion.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dateadd()` function :

```
select dateadd(day, t.int_time, 0) as joining_date
from tabel t;
```

You can use `update` statement to update , before that you need to alter table definition also :

```
alter table worker
    alter column int_time DATETIME

update worker
      set int_time = dateadd(day, t.int_time, 0)
```

`0` have a default date `1900-01-01 00:00:00.000`

Comment: What is happening here? This wont update the column, will it?

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[WORKER]
ALTER COLUMN [INT_TIME] DATETIME
```

This statement alters the integer column to a datetime column and parses the values automatically.